# security mismatch in with REST binding

Tags: wcf, rest, wcf-security

I wrote some wcf service that need to support SOAP and REST using IIS. 
The SOAP is working - and there is no problem with it. 
But when i call the REST from the explorer i get this message

```
       <Reason>
             <Text xml:lang="en-US">
                The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the 
                receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may 
                be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender 
                and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the  
                receiver. Check that sender 
                and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security 
                requirements, e.g. 
                Message, Transport, None).
            </Text>
       </Reason>
```

The Web.config file section that is relevant:

```
 <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Service.SOAPService">
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Contracts.ISOAPService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>

  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Service.RESTService" >
    <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Contracts.IRESTService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>

  .
  .
  .
   <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```